# problemas update de registro (ondelete on update)

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola buenas tardes a todos, nuevamente consultandoles lo siguiente: tengo una tabla(citas) en la cual requiero almacenar una serie de ID de otras tablas, entr ellos el idRegistro de un doctor, y el idRegistro de un funcionario, el insert bien pero cuando intenot hacer una edicion, me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

[image: Error]

[image: fks en la tabla citas]

en workbench, al crear las fk, existe una opción que dice ONUPDATE Y ONDELETE, las deje por defecto, pero posiblemente deba hacer el cambio ahí?
Alguien ha pasado por la misma situación?

Desde ya gracias por lo comentarios, saludos a todos...

Answer (score 0):

Estas obteniendo este error porque estas tratando de añadir o editar una fila en la tabla citas que no tiene una valor valido para el campo idRegistro basado en los valores que actualmente estan guardados en la tabla funcionario.  Asegurate que al agregar o editar valores, estos sean validos.